# Error loading angular module in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I would like to use angular module in node.js and use some of the APIs like angular.copy().

I followed the instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular

```
$ npm angular install --save
```

I add this simple line.

```
var angular = require('angular');
```

I get the following error;

```
node_modules\angular\angular.js:30578
})(window, document);
```

Does it mean the angular module cannot be used in node.js using `require`? If not, how can one use the angular module in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple anwser

You cant use angular module in NodeJS...

### More Detail

I mean there is a workaround to it.. You can check if it is angular or nodejs by the following code:

```
//Wrapper Function..
(function(isNode, isAngular) {

// This wrapper function returns the contents of your module, 
// with dependencies
var SampleModule= function(Bullet, Silver) {
  var Sample= function() {

  };
  return SilverBullet;    
};

if (isAngular) {
  // AngularJS module defining
  angular.module('app.appName', ['app.Module', 'app.Module']).
    factory('SilverBullet', ['Module', 'AnotherModule', BuleModule]);
} else if (isNode) {
  // NodeJS module defining
  module.exports = ModulesDefintion(
    require('module.js'), 
    require('anothermodule.js')
  );
}

})(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports,
  typeof angular !== 'undefined');
```

Basically:

> synchronous dependency handling in NodeJS works completely different than any client-side frameworks (which are asynchronous).

Learn More [here](https://gist.github.com/sevcsik/9207267#file-nodejs-angularjs-common-modules-md)